# Having issues with Leaflet + GIBS + EPSG4326

Tags: leaflet, tile-map-service

I've been having issues getting this to work correctly. Some details:

- I need to use Leaflet 1.0 or higher
- The map is BlueMarble ShadedRelief Bathymetry from NASA GIBS
- The map is EPSG:4326
- The map is loaded via TMS as opposed to WMS

[Here's the closest I've gotten so far.](http://wh.nerdfighteria.info/_views/timeline/maptest.php)

It seems to load and tile everything correctly, but some of the map isn't loading. Everything east of like 180 Longitude, and everything south of like -50 Latitude. I'm basing the code on the [example on NASA's site](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/labs/gibs/examples/leaflet/geographic-epsg4326.js), which works well (I got it working myself), but relies on an older version of Leaflet. After upgrading to a newer version, I've just run into a series of issues. I'm hoping someone can help me finally sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code looks like:

```
        map = L.map("map", {
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 8,
            maxBounds: [
                [-89.9999, -179.9999],
                [89.9999, 179.9999]
            ]
        });
...
        var crs = new L.Proj.CRS(
            "EPSG:4326",
            ....)
....
        var layer = L.tileLayer(template, {
            crs: crs,
            ....}
```

If you pay attention to the [Leaflet API reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html), you'll notice that `L.TileLayer`s **do not** have a `crs` option, and that `L.Map`s **do** have a `crs` option.

See also the "Notes to GIS users of WMS services" section of the [Leaflet tutorial on WMS](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html), as it contains an obvious example of a map with EPSG:4326 CRS.

Comment: I took a look at the example http://wh.nerdfighteria.info/_views/timeline/maptest.php now, and all the mistakes are commented out. Code is correct now but still no map is shown. When I looked at the network traffic I saw server returning status 301 for tile requests. Detailed look in Fiddler showed that server requires https requstest. So server template definition should start with "https://". I tested it and it works.

Comment: Few minutes later: initial map shows OK, but when zooming tiles are all over the place.

Comment: Another few minutes later: when option tms:true is removed from layer definition, it finally really works. Appologies for littering.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for the suggestions, that definitely improved things although I'm still working out a few issues. And yeah, TomazicM, I've been working on it right now which is why things are constantly changing. Right now I just can't get the southernmost and easternmost regions to appear. I've been messing around with Bounds and MaxBounds but haven't fixed it yet.

Comment: The following options are missing in layer definition: noWrap: true,  continuousWorld: true,

Comment: Figured it out, there was an issue with the tileSize property. I guess the value was wrong, but just omitting it entirely fixed the issue. Thanks for the help -- the code is definitely a lot cleaner now.